# ObjectBox - Given relation with ID XX does not include this box type (ENTITY_NAME)

Tags: database, flutter, relation, objectbox

On my Flutter app, I've found this error in Crashlytics after an update.
I didn't reproduce it yet on my dev environment, meaning that I don't really know what triggers this problem.

I know that this issue is triggered when I fetch a list of Entities from my Backend and try to persist it locally.
The model I'm saving contains the following :

```
  @JsonKey(
    toJson: WorkerToManyConverter.toJson,
    fromJson: WorkerToManyConverter.fromJson,
  )
  ToMany<Worker> availableAgents = ToMany();
```

and in the error message that I displayed as a title, (ENTITY_NAME) is (WORKER)
but I don't really understand why I'd have such an error triggered.

Comment: Hi, Uwe from ObjectBox here! This error message indicates that ObjectBox did not find the relation for the Worker box. We have not seen this before, so we would welcome more details if possible (e.g. what changed in your update, how entities are put) on our issue tracker at https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues